# I am creating React native application and i face the issue in open pop-up modal box on FlatList

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am creating the react native application and I have video data and I want to share my video data information with other people,
[image: My design something like below]
I want to open a pop-up modal box with the click of that icon, with this particular video information

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.videoData}
    renderItem={this.renderItemOffer}
    keyExtractor={(it, index) => String(index)}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
/>
```

I am using the flat list for rendering the data

```
_onPressItem = (item) => {
    this._showModal(item);
};
_showModal = (selectedItem) => this.setState({ isShareModal: true, selectedItem })

renderItemOffer = ({ item }) => (
    <>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ borderRadius: 25 }}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("VideoPlay")}
        >
            <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
                "Video Thumnail and video data"
              <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this._onPressItem(item)} >
                    <Icon name='more-vertical' size={30} color={colors.black} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal
            visible={(this.state.isShareModal)}
            selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.shareMessage(item)} style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Share</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    </>
)
```

Comment: Hey remove these remove these round bracket inside modal tag may be this is the issue   visible={this.state.isShareModal}

Answer (score 1):

you just need declare Modal one time, move it out of your item,
something like:

```
<>
<FlatList
    data={this.state.videoData}
    renderItem={this.renderItemOffer}
    keyExtractor={(it, index) => String(index)}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
/>
<Modal
            visible={(this.state.isShareModal)}
            selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.shareMessage(this.state.selectedItem)} style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Share</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
</Modal>
</>
```